# Javascript hardcoded variables

Tags: javascript, variables, hardcoded

I have a simple js file:

```
//base.js

...
var url = '/post/' + id + '/comment';
...
```

I'm using Symfony2 so on the server side all the urls are generated by the Router, and it bugs me that I use hardcoded urls in the js..

Is there a way to make them more dynamic?
Those are the solutions I thought about but I'm **not** happy with:

- Defining them in the HTML tags like `<div data-url="<?php path('post_comment'); ?>">`
- Defining them in an inline script tag `<script language="text/javascript">...</script>`

I think that the urls in the js files of some big sites (SO, GitHub, etc.) are hardcoded, am I right?

Comment: One alternative example I can think of - is generation of the urls map on the build step (and saving them in a javascript object)

Comment: I ended up declaring a global namespace object and inserting all the paths I needed as properties of that object. I didn't like it one bit... it's a limitation of Symphony that has turned me off to the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Friends of Symfony JS Routing Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) was made exactly for your needs

```
var url = Routing.generate('some_route_to_expose', { foo: 'bar' });
// url is http://somehost.com/app_dev.php/my_route
```

The bundle also lets you dump, compile and minify the resulting javascript. Its great!

Answer (score 0):

You should at least minimize namespace pollution by defining all your constant variables inside a configuration object and access it using the property name or getter functions.